# Display Record Name in Another Page After Clicking the Save Button Using Apex and Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I can't fetch the name of the record (**Name**) of the info I've just inserted. The requirement is after clicking the save button, a new page will appear, displaying the information I've saved. Problem is, I don't know how to get the record name (this is auto-generated). Any help, especially sample codes will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Controller:**

```
public class attachmentExample{


    public Id parentId{get;set;}
    public Boolean Page1{get;set;}
    public Boolean Page2{get;set;}
    public Book__c book{get;set;}
    public Book__c book1{get;set;}
    public String bookName{get;set;}  

    public attachmentExample(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {


        Page1 = true;
        Page2 = false; 
        book = new Book__c();
    }

    public pagereference sendAttach()
    {

        book1 = new Book__c();


        book1.Title__c = book.Title__c;
        book1.Author__c = book.Author__c;
        book1.Price__c = book.Price__c;
        book1.Publisher__c = book.Publisher__c;

        insert book1;
        parentId = book1.Id;



        //book1 = [SELECT Id, Name, Title__c, Price__c, Author__c, Publisher__c FROM Book__c WHERE Id =: book1.Id];



        //System.assertequals(book1.Name + 'test','');

        Page1 = false;
        Page2 = true;


        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage semail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        PageReference pref = page.BookDetails;
        pref.getParameters().put('id',(String)book1.Id);
        pref.setRedirect(true);
        Blob b = pref.getContent();
        attach.setFileName('BookDetails.pdf');
        attach.setBody(b);
        semail.setSubject('Book details');
        String[] sendTo = new String[]{'latosa.gizelle@gmail.com'};
        semail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
        semail.setPlainTextBody('Please find the attached book details');
        semail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{attach});
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{semail});

        Attachment appPdf = new Attachment();
        appPdf.Body = Page.BookDetails.getContentAsPdf();
        appPdf.ContentType = '.pdf';
        appPdf.Name = 'Book Details';
        appPdf.ParentId = parentId;
        insert appPdf;
        parentId = null;
        return null;





    }
}
```

Visualforce1: **BookPage**

```
<apex:page standardController="Book__c" extensions="attachmentExample">
   <apex:form >
       <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!Page1}" >



                <div>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!sendAttach}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel"/>
                </div>

                <apex:pageBlockSection >


                <apex:inputField value="{!book.Title__c}"/><br/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!book.Author__c}"/><br/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!book.Price__c}"/><br/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!book.Publisher__c}"/>

                </apex:pageBlockSection>

       </apex:pageBlock>

       <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!Page2}">
           <apex:outputLabel >New Book has been inserted. Please check your email to confirm details.</apex:outputLabel>
       </apex:pageBlock>

   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Visualforce 2: **BookDetails**

```
<apex:page standardController="Book__c" extensions="attachmentExample" renderAs="pdf" docType="html-5.0">



    <apex:form > 
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">

            <apex:outputText Value="{!book.Name}"/> 
            <apex:outputText Value="{!book.Title__c}"/>
            <apex:outputText Value="{!book.Author__c}"/>
            <apex:outputText Value="{!book.Price__c}"/>
            <apex:outputText Value="{!book.Publisher__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>


</apex:page>
```

Comment: it seems like you are asking people to do you work. It would be great if you can put some initial effort on your problem and then share your  code. If you are don't know how to start you can start learning from trailhead. https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/module/visualforce_fundamentals

Comment: Hi sorry, I don't mean it that way. I've already inserted what I've made, please see my edited post.

Answer (score 1):

if you will go through the [trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/module/visualforce_fundamentals) you will find that you need to pass record id on your second page. once you will pass record id you will see record name and rest of the fields.

Here is the description from Salesforce documentation

> Provide the record ID for a record to the standard controller by
>   adding it as a parameter in the request URL. If you want to use the
>   standard controller to reference a specific record, it needs to know
>   the record identifier, or ID, of the record to work with. It uses the
>   ID to retrieve the data, and to save it back to the database when the
>   record’s data is changed.

You are using Book__c as record controller so you need to pass book__c record id after insertion.

In your case there are two options.

1. You can directly redirect on bookdetail page after inserting the record in following way from **sendAttach** method

   PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/BookDetails' + book1.id);
   pageRef.setRedirect(true);
   return pageRef;
2. You can put a url on your page which will lead to your bookdetails page and you will add record id

Answer (score 0):

here is some reference code .. you can refer too. here you see when i insert a custom object record by apex.. the next thing is to assign the page reference regPage with the URL for the details page of newly created record.

```
public PageReference save() {
    insert reguser ; 
    PageReference regPage = new PageReference('/' + reguser.id);
    regPage.setRedirect(true);

    User U1 = [SELECT Id, Name ,Email FROM User where id = :UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];

    Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(1);
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'rachit.j@101bi.com'};
    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
    mail.setReplyTo(U1.Email);
    mail.setSenderDisplayName(U1.Name);
    mail.setSubject('Register User Request ID: ' + reguser.Id);
    mail.setBccSender(false);
    mail.setUseSignature(false);
    mail.setPlainTextBody('Register User Request ID: ' + reguser.Id + ' Request Sign Sign On permission with Website Username : ' + reguser.Salesforce_Username__c + ' with OTP :' + reguser.OTP__c + ' for website : ' + reguser.Website__c );
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });


    return regPage;

    }    

}
```

Comment: @Himanshu if this ans solved your issue. the pls accept the ans and upvote. :)